# how to find postgresql syntax error at position (using eclipse)

Tags: java, postgresql, syntax-error

I am using Postgres for sql within eclipse and i ran my code and it gave me an error

```
syntax error at end of input position 13
```

however, I'm a bit confused as to find position 13 because I am using eclipse and I have written about 200 lines of code and I don't think it is line 13..

I don't know if I'm being stupid but I don't know how to find the error at the said position because I don't know how to find the position!

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM BRANCH";
    ResultSet rs = executeQuery(connection, query);
    try {
   
      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("Column 1 returned");
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      }
       
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rs.close();
   
    dropTable(connection, " delayedFlights");
    createTable(connection," delayedFlights( ID_of_Delayed_Flight int pr"
        + "imary key, month int, dayOfMonth int, dayOfWeek int, depTime int, scheduledDeptTime int, arrTime int, "
        + "scheduledArrTime int, uniqueCarrier varchar(5), flightNum int, actualFlightTime int, scheduledFlightTime int,"
        + "airTime int, arrDelay int, depDelay int, orig varchar(5), dest varchar(5), distance int);");
    int rows = insertIntoTableFromFile(connection, "delayedFlights", "src/delayedFlights.txt");
    System.out.println(rows + " rows inserted.");
   
    dropTable(connection, " airport");
    createTable(connection, " airport( airportCode int primary key, airportName varchar(20), city varchar(25),"
        + "state varchar(25));");
    int rows2 = insertIntoTableFromFile(connection, "airport", "src/airport.txt");
    System.out.println(rows2 + " rows inserted.");
```

Comment: It's **position** 13, not "line 13". And the position 1 is the first character of your SQL statement (_not_ your Java code - Postgres doesn't even see that). But without showing us the actual SQL query, this is impossible to answer.